# Organizing Localized Variables and using Context

Tags: manipulate, contexts

I have been developing a program that requires me to use `LocalizedVariables->False` for some variables. However, I am having a difficult time redirecting these variables to another context as this command defaults the program to the Global setting.

Is it possible to control the context location of the variables you wish to apply `LocalizedVariables->False`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you meant `LocalizeVariables`. You could do it like this:

```
Remove[x, Test`x]
Begin["Test`"]
`x = 0
{Manipulate[x, {x, 0, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False], Dynamic[Test`x]}
End[]
```